# How to apply scipy.signal.filtfilt() on incomplete data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to plot incomplete data (some values are None). In addition I want to apply a butter function on the dataset and show both graphs, incomplete and smoothened. The filter function seems to not work with incomplete data.

Data File: [data.csv](https://ufile.io/7xur2)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

data = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter = ',')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)

b, a = signal.butter(5, 0.1)
y = signal.filtfilt(b,a, df[1].values)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(y, index=df.index)

df.plot()
df2.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html) does not mention anything related to NaN. You may have to first remove the NaN from your list of values. Here is a way to do it using Numpy isnan function:

```
y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, df[1].values[~np.isnan(df[1].values)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(y, index=df.index[~np.isnan(df[1].values)])
```

Comment: That *might* be a reasonable solution.  But the filter functions in `scipy.signal` assume the data is sampled at regular intervals.  If you discard the `nan` values, the sample periods of the remaining data are no longer consistent, and that may invalidate the filter results.

Comment: In this case one would have to first manually resample the data at a lower frequency to match the removal of NaN values ?

Comment: Interpolate the data before filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I did not find anything useful elsewhere so I did this (might not be the quickest, but still works). I am posting it here is case it can help someone else :)

```
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

b, a = signal.butter(4, 0.15)
data_filtered = np.zeros((len(data)))
data_filtered[:] = np.nan
while_bool = True
current_index = 0
if np.where(np.isnan(data))[0][0] == 0:
    next_number = np.where(~np.isnan(data))[0][0]
    current_index += next_number
else:
    next_number = 0
while while_bool:
    if np.shape(np.where(np.isnan(data[next_number:]))[0]) == (0,):
        next_nan = len(data)
        while_bool = False
    else:
        next_nan = np.where(np.isnan(data[next_number:]))[0]
        next_nan = next_nan[0] + current_index
        current_index = next_nan
    data_filtered[next_number:next_nan] = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data[next_number:next_nan])
    next_number = np.where(~np.isnan(data[next_nan:]))[0]
    if np.shape(next_number) == (0,):
        while_bool = False
    else:
        next_number = next_number[0] + current_index
        current_index = next_number
```

[Gave this filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEQXy.png)